# Hi, i need to hide warning message and replace some custom text like: "URL is incorrect"

Tags: php, warnings, file-get-contents

Warning: file_get_contents(http://dddd.ge/): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\vidow\index.php on line 15

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="url">
    <button name="btn" id="btn">SEARCH</button>
</form> 

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['btn'])) { 
        $src = $_POST['url']; 
        if (empty($src)) { 
            echo "Please type URL";
        }else{ 
            $html = file_get_contents($src);
            echo $html;
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code which generates the error, it will help in providing an answer.

Comment: <form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="url">
 <button name="btn" id="btn">SEARCH</button>
</form>
<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {

  $src = $_POST['url'];

  if (empty($src)) {
   echo "Please type URL";
  }else{
   $html = file_get_contents($src);
   echo $html;
  }

 }
?>

Answer (score -1):

I think yo should first hide the warnings (unless if you are in dev environment, because they can be usefull):

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

And then you could handle the error, for example like this:

```
$file_headers = @get_headers($src);
if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    // your wrong url message...
    echo 'URL is incorrect: '.$src;
}
else{
    //your normal code...
    file_get_contents($src);
}
```

Comment: If you check for `file_exists()` first, you shouldn't get any warnings, so disabling them seems like a bad idea (IMHO).

Comment: @NigelRen well thats true. Good point :) Let say most of the time you want warnings enabled in dev environment, and disabled in prod environment.

Comment: @yenimal i edited my answer with what i use to check if remote url exists,